# Поиск максимальной суммы в подмассиве

Tags: c++, python, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив, требуется найти такой подмассив с максимальной суммой элементов в нем, чтобы начало и конец отрезка были одинаковыми(вывести их индексы также). Сложность O(n).
В голову ничего не приходит, кроме как с помощью вложенного цикла перебрать все элементы, но это уже O(n^2). Пример: [3,5,3,6,5] ответ: 19 ( 5+3+6+5)

Comment: Ограничения по памяти есть?

Comment: ограничения по памяти отсутствуют

Comment: Тогда используйте map, где в качестве ключа подрузумевается текущий  элемент массива, а в значениях лежит структура с полями позиция первого элемента, сумма, позиция последнего. В цикле обходите ваш массив, проверяя есть в ключах мар значение текущего элемента, если нет, то создаете новую структуру , добавляете ее map и добавляете к суммам всех структур этот элемент, если есть, то выводите его из map, заносите его позицию как конечный элемент, выводите его из map и добавляете в SortedList, ранжированный по сумам. После прохождения цикла извлекаете из него искомую подпоследоватнельнсть.

Comment: Кто-нибудь объяснит за что минуса?

Comment: @Андрей Москаленко минус за хитрость. Это не вопрос, а просьба студента сделать на халяву за себя свою работу. Задача элементарная, но автором, не были продемонстрировано попыток разобраться самостоятельно.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов вы неверно представляете себе цели и задачи сайта. Полезность вопроса измеряется не усилиями автора, а скольким людям вопрос может помочь. 90+% трафика на Stack Overflow из веб-поисковиков. [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: @jfs, безусловно "...полезность вопроса измеряется не усилиями автора, а скольким людям вопрос может помочь..", поэтому встречный вопрос, кому кроме студента, задавшего данный вопрос, будет полезен ответ на него. Вот пример "глупого", но несомненно полезного вопроса, интересного многим. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766800/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-base-onformclosing-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5

Comment: @jfs сходил по ссылке, совершенно согласен  автором поднявшем проблему на "мете" и внимательно прочел Ваш ответ. Очевидно, что к "учебным" вопросам нужен дифференцированный ответ. Также очевидно, что данный вопрос имеет ценность только для автора, которому нужно сдать сессию.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов 1- ваш первый комментарий ничего не говорил о полезности вопроса для других программистов, а только озабочен леностью автора вопроса: *"Это не вопрос, а просьба студента сделать на халяву за себя свою работу."* ¶ 2- полезность для других программистов может быть неочевидна, но глупо утверждать, что достаточно общая алгоритмическая задача, только одному человеку может быть полезна (я не первый раз с этой задачей сталкиваюсь). Вы напоминаете людей, которые говорят "зачем косинусы нужны, я никогда их в жизни не использовал"

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов вот официальная точка зрения управляющего сообществом: [Допустимы ли вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4882/23044)

Comment: @jfs, боюсь что Вы допустили некоторую умственную небрежность, и не заметили, что первый комментарий к вопросу, был утонением вопроса, после которого студент получил исчерпывающую подсказку, на которую не последовало реакции. Но не будем об этом. Мне стало интересно, где  Вы еще сталкивались с этой "...достаточно общей алгоритмической задачей"? И давайте все-таки     будем точны: "...Вы напоминаете людей, которые говорят "зачем косинусы нужны, я никогда их в жизни не использовал..." - где и когда я говорил, то что Вы мне приписали?

Comment: @jfs, сходил по Вашей новой ссылке, совершенно с ней согласен. Но русский язык богат и на первый взгляд, просто измененный порядок слов может кого-то обидеть. Поэтому, будем аккуратными в выражениях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим элемент `a_i` и некоторый отрезок `[j..i]` (то есть отрезок, для которого элемент `a_i` является последним). По условию нас интересуют только отрезки, у которых `a_j == a_i`. Поймём, какой из таких отрезков даёт наибольшую сумму. Распишем сумму отрезка (нумерация элементов в массиве с единицы):

```
sum([j..i]) = sum([1..i]) - sum([1..(j-1)])
```

Таким образом, для фиксированного `i` достаточно найти такой `j`, что `sum([1..(j-1)])` минимальна. Это можно сделать с помощью [хеш-таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), в которой для каждого числа `a_i` будем хранить минимальную из сумм `sum([1..(j-1)])` для всех подходящих `j`.

```
typedef long long ll;

// для удобства добавим в начало массива ноль
vector<int> a = {0 /* extra zero */, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5};
// элементы массива индексируются [1..n]
int n = a.size() - 1;

// префиксные суммы
// cumsum[k] := a[1] + ... + a[k]
vector<ll> prefixSums;
for (int ai : a)
    prefixSums.push_back(prefixSums.empty() ? 0 : prefixSums.back() + ai);

// сумма на отрезке a_j ... a_i равна сумме на префиксе [1..i] минус сумме на префиксе [1..j-1]
// по условию задачи рассматриваются только такие суммы, что a_j == a_i
// будем итерироваться по массиву и для каждого числа a_j запоминать минимальную сумму на префиксе [1..j-1]
// при встрече очередного числа a_i будем обновлять ответ, рассматривая отрезок [j..i]
unordered_map<int, ll> numberToMinSum;
ll answer = numeric_limits<ll>::min();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (numberToMinSum.find(a[i]) != numberToMinSum.end()) {
        numberToMinSum[a[i]] = min(numberToMinSum[a[i]], prefixSums[i - 1]);
        answer = max(answer, prefixSums[i] - numberToMinSum[a[i]]);
    } else {
        numberToMinSum[a[i]] = prefixSums[i - 1];
    }
}
cout << answer << endl;
```

[Проверка на Ideone](https://ideone.com/st01LP).

Comment: Для примера [-1,-1,-1] программа выводит -2, а верный ответ -1. Получается, что нужно просто доп условие на проверку отрицательного ответа? К сожалению, в ++ не силен: как вывести индексы границ?

Comment: @user1337157 исправил для [-1, -1, -1], раньше не рассматривались все отрезки длины 1

Comment: @diraria, ИМХО я бы не стал в данном случае делать за соискателя его работу и писать код. Им не было предложено своего решения :). ИМХО достаточно было просто подсказки.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов утверждение, что полезный вопрос обязан решение автора содержать абсолютно неверно. Более того ответ с рабочим кодом гораздо полезней для посетителей из гугла с похожей проблемой нежели "подсказки". [Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044)