# Какой смысл инструкции base.OnFormClosing() в одноименном методе?

Tags: c#, winforms

В коде события, в одном из примеров, увидел следующее:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Написан код, который сохраняет пользовательские данные
    //

    base.OnFormClosing(e); //Интересна именно эта строчка
}
```

Какой смысл несет последняя строка? Для чего она нужна и когда используется?

Comment: В этой строчке три слова и четыре знака препинания. Напишите точнее, что именно вызывает затруднения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите, в чём смысл виртуальных методов вообще? Он в том, что вы полностью подменяете метод родительского класса на свой. И теперь ответственность за то, чтобы сделать всё правильно, лежит на вас.

Но чаще всего это *слишком большая* ответственность: вы не знаете/не помните всех вещей, которые должен сделать метод. Или просто не хотите дублировать код родительского метода.

В этом случае вы просто вызываете родительский метод через `base`, он делает всё, что требуется от данного кода, а вы добавляете свой код до, после или вокруг вызова `base`-метода. Таким образом вы можете гарантировать, что вы ничего не забыли сделать при подмене метода.

Comment: эхх... такой хороший ответа и на такой плохой вопрос.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов: Хороший ответ может спасти плохой вопрос, превратив его в нормальный вопрос :)

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов даже галочка перепрыгнула..

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов: Прошу прощения за то, что украл вашу галочку

Comment: @VladD ничего страшного. полностью заслуженно.

Comment: Ответ замечательный, теперь хорошо бы сформулировать под него вопрос :) Сейчас ответ сложно найти в поиске и нельзя использовать для закрытия дублей.

Comment: @defaultlocale: «почему в методах наподобие `OnSomething` часто встречается `base.OnSomething`?», например?

Answer (score 4):

Ключевое слово [base](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) используется для доступа к членам базового из производного класса.

То есть после сохранения пользовательских данных вызывается функция из производного класса. Подобное нужно если в базовом классе есть какой то функционал который нужны вызвать до/(или как в данном случае)после выполнения функции из дочернего класса.